# Proof of coset and normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

I have this question:

> Let $G$ be a group, $a,b\in G$ and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.
>
> i) Give the definition of the coset $aH$
>
> ii) Prove that $aH = bH$ if and only if $a^{-1}b\in H$
>
> iii) Suppose $H = \{1,h\}$ has exactly $2$ elements. If $H \unlhd G$ prove that $gh=hg$ for every $g\in G$

My attempts:
i) $aH = \{ah| h \in H\}$

ii) Let me just roll with it, this is sort of what I was getting at(but didn't know how to do it):

($\to$) $aH = bH$, $ah = bh$, so $h = a^{-1}bh$, since obviously $h\in H$, $a^{-1}bh \in H$, but we also not $h=a^{-1}bh=h \to 1=a^{-1}b$, so $a=b$

($\leftarrow$) $a^{-1}b\in H$ then $a^{-1}b = h$, $b=ah$, $bH=aH$, that last step is probably not valid at all. Lost there

iii) $H \unlhd G$, so $g^{-1}hg\in H$

We have two values of $h$

$h=1$ $g^{-1}hg=g^{-1}*1*g=g^{-1}g=1$, obviously here $g*1=1*g$, $g=g$

$h=h$ $gh=hg$ is trivial case(Actually it might not be since it isn't abelian).

So what if it doesn't commute: $g^{-1}hg=h$, $hg=gh$ hence they commute.

Is any of this actually right?

Comment: For (ii), if $aH = bH$, then there may not exists $h\in H$ such that $ah=bh$. It just means that $\forall h_1\in H, \exists h_2\in H$ such that $ah_1 = bh_2$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan True, will edit in update soon

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan This is probably a silly question, but how are elements rearranged here(I am fairly sure I don't have commutability), is this an illegal operation?

$abc=def$, $ac=b^{-1}def$

Can I only take something off of the front here and put it on the front of the other, eg $bc=a^{-1}def$

Comment: You cannot take anything off anywhere and put it somewhere else. What you **can** do is to do the same thing to two equal objects and they will remain equal. Never "transfer" elements around without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: @user21820 That makes sense, and if I have $a^{-1} b a$ I can't say it equals $b$, because they can't inverse without operating on $b$ first.

Comment: Yep; though you probably mean "without operating on $a$ first".

Comment: @User21820 Just clarifying with that operating thing, it does still do $a^{-1}b=q$ first, and then $qa$

Comment: Ok I see what you meant. Yes. And when you have $x = y$ you can only multiply on the right to both or on the left to both.

Comment: I clicked that chat thing completely by accident haha.

I understand now, thank you!

Comment: @user142198: Okay you're welcome! Don't forget this principle, since it applies to functions as well and not just elements of a group. Moreover you can think of multiplying by a group element (on a particular side) as a function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $aH$ is correct.

For (ii), suppose first that $aH = bH$.  Since $1\in H$, therefore, $b = b1\in bH$ and, since $aH=bH$, it follows that $b\in aH$. Thus, there is an element $h\in H$ such that $b = ah$. Multiplying by $a^{-1}$ on the left, we get $a^{-1}b = a^{-1}ah = h\in H$.

Conversely, assume that $a^{-1}b\in H$.  Then $b = 1b = (aa^{-1})b = a(a^{-1}b) = ah_{1} \in aH$, where $h_{1} = a^{-1}b$.  Now take any $bh_{2}\in bH$.  Then $bh_{2} = (ah_{1})h_{2} = a(h_{1}h_{2})\in aH$, since $h_{1}h_{2}\in H$.  This shows that $bH\subseteq aH$.  You can fill in a similar argument to show that $aH\subseteq bH$.

For (iii), the assumption that $H\unlhd G$ tells you that $g^{-1}Hg = H$, for any $g\in G$.  This means (just writing it out) that
$$\{g^{-1}1g, g^{-1}hg \} = \{ 1, h \},$$
for any $g\in G$.  Now, suppose that $g\in G$ is arbitrary.  You want to show that $hg = gh$.  Can you simplify the left hand side of the displayed set equality to help you come to this conclusion?